# Assignments with after and signals

Tags: vhdl, simulation, delay

I am trying to understand how assignments with 'after foo' work, so I read about the delay model and simulated the following code:

```
library IEEE;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity test is
    port (
          goes_in, goes_out : out std_logic := 'U'
         );
end entity;

architecture a of test is
signal temp  : std_logic := 'U';
signal input : std_logic := 'Z';

begin
    goes_in <= input;
process (input)
    begin
    temp <= input;
    goes_out <= temp after 10ns; -- (*)
    end process;

--Removing the line with the (*) and uncommenting the following snippet solves the problem.
--process (temp)
--    begin
--    goes_out <= temp after 10ns;
--    end process;    
process
    begin
    input <= '0';
    wait for 15 ns;
    input <= '1';
    wait;
    end process;    
end a;
```

In Xilinx's Vivaldo, I get the following output:

```
time(ns) :            10      15      20      25
                              _________   ________________________  ...  
goes_in  : _______'0'________/         '1'

goes_out : ----'U'-----|---------'Z'----------\_____'0'___________  ...
```

When what I expected was simply a 10ns delay. Can someone explain what is going on here?

---

EDIT: To be clear, my beef here is that, if the behaviour I'm describing is indeed default, it sounds like an awful leak of abstraction: when I write

```
goes_out <= temp after 10ns;
```

the behavior I expect would be one that simulates a latch being driven (temp is the input, goes_out is the output), and so temp would have to keep its new value for 10ns in order to properly drive the latch (hence the "inertial delay" model).

Now, if this were indeed the case, the proper behaviour for my circuit would be to do nothing, since I attempt to write a 'Z' to goes_out and immediately after that, that 'Z' is overwritten by a '1' - therefore, the value of temp driving the latch is not kept, and it fails to drive goes_out. (obviously you can't drive latches with 'Z', thought I could use '0' and '1' and my point would stand)

So my question is: is there a good reason for this odd behaviour? To me, it seems trivial to "make things right": the algorithm that simulates the inertial delay could check for changes in the value of temp in the delta cycle it is being assigned to goes_out, and cancel the assignment if something is happening - instead of only cancelling the assignment if the NEW value of temp does not change.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is your use of `<=`, which causes assignments to happen in parallel.

Consider the assignment of 1 to `input`. That triggers the `process(input)`. The first line `temp <= input;` effectively queues the assignment of 1 to `temp` *immediately after the current time step*. `temp` retains the value of 0 for the execution of the next line, which is interpreted as "queue the assignment of the value that `temp` had at the start of this process to be assigned to `goes_out` in 10ns time".

If you collapse it to `goes_out <= input after 10ns;` and remove `temp` entirely, it looks a bit more intuitive. Or view the values of temp and input in your simulator.

Answer (score 1):

```
process
begin
    temp <= input;
    goes_out <= temp after 10ns; -- (*)
end process;
```

`temp` hasn't change by the time you read it to assign it to `goes_out`.  Until some time passes (ie all the processes triggered during this delta cycle have completed) any assignments made in those processes are merely scheduled to happen at the next time step.

You could do:

```
process
begin
    wait until input'event;
    temp <= input;
    wait for 0 ps;
    goes_out <= temp after 10ns;
end process;
```

The `wait for 0 ps;` forces some time to pass (0ps counts as forcing delta cycles to finish)

Comment: Didn't work. The compiler says:
"process cannot have both a wait statement and a sensitivity list".

Comment: Yes, I didn't put a complete process in, it was just to show how to make time pass.  See update for code which shows the whole process